# Is it safe to always use === in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I just ran across a day-wasting bug because I didn't realize that the PHP == operator does type coercion similar to Javascript.

I know that Douglas Crockford recommends never using the == operator with Javascript, and to always use the === operator.

If I code in a manner that never assumes type coercion, can I use the same advice in PHP, and never use the == operator?  is it safe to **always** use the === operator, or are there gotchas that I need to be aware of?

Comment: I have written several CMS and PHP frameworks doing just about every type of operation and data transformation PHP can do. I still use both `==` and `===` since they solve different problems. However, in the real world `===` really should be used more than it is.

Comment: I cant remember the last time i actually used the loose comparison versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `===` by default (to avoid the problems you just encountered) and use `==` when needed, as a convenience.

For instance, you may be taking parameters from `$_GET` or similar, and a parameter might be the string `true` or `false`, vs the boolean `true` or `false`.  Personally, I check everything, but there can be legitimate use cases for `==` if you are conscious of it, and careful with use.

Answer (score 4):

`==` and `===`, exist for specific reasons. As you've already mentioned in your post, `==` does type coercion.

I come from a strongly typed programming background, and thus never require type coercion, quite like you. In this case, it is safe to always use `===`.

Of course, when you do require coercion, use `==`.

In case of inputs you have no control over (GET/POST parameters, API responses) you could either use `==` or use casting.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump('1' == 1);` return `bool(true)` and `var_dump('1' === 1);` return `bool(false)` because they have the same value but different types. One is string and other is int.

Only use `===` if you know the type you are checking.